# Progress 9.1e reverse engineer into ERwin failing

Tags: odbc, progress-db

When I reverse engineer from a Progress 9.1e database I get the following error message:

"Column _Desc in table pub._File has value exceeding its max length of precision"

Is this a configuration of the secondary (SQL) broker that I need to set on the Progress server?

Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress uses variable length fields for it's character fields, so if a record's field data length is > the SQL width, the result is errors like this.

You'll need to either change the SQL width of the _File table or shorten the data in the offending _file._desc record.

Keep in mind that the _file tables are part of the db schema, so messing with them directly isn't recommended.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'd modify this using the Data Administraction tool, data dictionary tool.

Comment: So are you going to upvote and mark my answer as 'the' answer? :)

Comment: Thanks! (text to keep SE this happy)